# Blank image thumbnails in media library

Tags: images, media-library, migration, permissions, thumbnails

I copied one website to other domain. i am using avada theme

in my new domain all images show as blank thumbnails in admin but in website all images are show

i checked permission of all folder and images, i gave permission 775 for folder and 664 for images, however blank thumbnails show in media library

can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: what is the path of <img> tag into inspect elements ?

Comment: mydomain/wp-includes/images/media/default.png

Comment: https://www.mhthemes.com/support/fix-blank-thumbnails-wordpress-media-library/ I have found some comman issue with Media library. try to solve it.

Comment: "permission 775 for folder and 664 for images" ? Use permission 755 for folder and 644 for images